# Queuing Actions/Delegates for Asyncronous Execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, delegates

Is there something in the framework that would allow me to asynchronously execute a queue of delegates?

What I mean by that is I want the delegates to execute one at a time in the order they are queued but I want this whole process to run asynchronously. The queue is not fixed either, additional delegates would be added periodically and should be processed as soon as it reaches the top of the queue.

I don't need to use a `Queue` in particular, it's just how I would describe the desired behavior.

I could write something myself to do it but if there is something built in I could use instead that would be better.

I briefly looked at `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` as it allows executing in order but could find a satisfactory way to prevent more than one execution at a time.

Comment: What part exactly should be asynchronous? the queueing? or the actions themselves have to be async?

Comment: @I3arnon Sorry should have made that clear, the actions should execute asynchronously, the act of queuing should execute synchronously or the order could potentially be changed, although it is not essential.

Comment: @I3arnon I'm not even sure that is clear. What I mean is, the action of queueing should block until the action has been queued. After that everything should happen on another thread including the execution of the actions. But I still need them to execute one at a time.

Comment: Then my answer should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something in the framework that would allow me to
>   asynchronously execute a queue of delegates?

I'd implement this as a custom task scheduler. You could then queue and run your delegates as tasks, which would give you all benefits of exception handling, cancellation, and `async/await`.

Implementing a task scheduler which would execute your delegates in the serial order is quite simple, using `BlockingCollection`. The `SerialTaskScheduler` below is a simplified version of [Stephen Toub's `StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console_21628490
{
    // Test
    class Program
    {
        static async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            using (var scheduler = new SerialTaskScheduler())
            {
                var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i =>
                    scheduler.Run(() =>
                    {
                        var sleep = 1000 / i;
                        Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                        Console.WriteLine("Task #" + i + ", sleep: " + sleep);
                    }, CancellationToken.None));

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoWorkAsync().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    // SerialTaskScheduler
    public sealed class SerialTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
    {
        Task _schedulerTask;
        BlockingCollection<Task> _tasks;
        Thread _schedulerThread;

        public SerialTaskScheduler()
        {
            _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();

            _schedulerTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _schedulerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

                foreach (var task in _tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    TryExecuteTask(task);
            });
        }

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            _tasks.Add(task);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            return _tasks.ToArray();
        }

        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(
            Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return _schedulerThread == Thread.CurrentThread &&
                TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_schedulerTask != null)
            {
                _tasks.CompleteAdding();
                _schedulerTask.Wait();
                _tasks.Dispose();
                _tasks = null;
                _schedulerTask = null;
            }
        }

        public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this);
        }

        public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this).Unwrap();
        }

        public Task<T> Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, this).Unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Task #1, sleep: 1000
Task #2, sleep: 500
Task #3, sleep: 333
Task #4, sleep: 250
Task #5, sleep: 200
Task #6, sleep: 166
Task #7, sleep: 142
Task #8, sleep: 125
Task #9, sleep: 111
Task #10, sleep: 100
```

Comment: Thank you this was also very helpful and must have been a lot of work. I can also use this solution without upgrading to 4.5.

Comment: @Ashigore, no problem, most of the work has been done by Stephen Toub here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx

Comment: The links to Stephen Toub StaScheduler do not work anymore, use this: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TPL dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and simply queue up a class that holds a `Delegate` and a lists of parameters. The `ActionBlock` will simply executes those delegates one at a time.

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Item>(_ => _.Action.DynamicInvoke(_.Paramters));

class Item
{
    public Delegate Action { get; private set; }
    public object[] Parameters { get; private set; }

    public Item(Delegate action, object[] parameters)
    {
        Action = action;
        Parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

An even easier option would be to use an `ActionBlock` of [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that forces you to capture the parameters:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Action>(action => action());

block.Post(() => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

Comment: If for example, all my delegates had the same signature, could I use for example `new ActionBlock<Action<string>>` for actions with 1 string parameter?

Comment: @Ashigore Yes. But remember that's a very specific solution.

Comment: OK I understand, thank you very much for your help on this question.